# I can not remove malware from a laptop?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, virus, malware-removal

A computer virus is driving me crazy. The virus types "x" continuously wherever it finds a text field and at the top of open applications ( where the name of the application is displayed). This means logging in is impossible, as soon as a the login boxes are seen, they are populated with "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx". I restored my computer, I then reset it, I downloaded malwarebytes and many other programs, I deleted disks from disk management, I finally installed Ubuntu, none of these helped. I have no idea what to do now and to make things worse the laptop has started making a continues beeping sound, I can only stop the sound if I shut the computer. What are my options, what else can I try?

Comment: May be it's not a virus, it's just that the "x" key is stuck, and that's why your laptop makes the beeping when you restart it

Comment: @fernando.reyes You can type faster than me. I was just about to post the exact same comment.

Comment: @fernando.reyes - yeah, that'd be my guess, too.

Comment: Since you appear to be using a laptop, you could try unplugging the integrated keyboard and plug in an external one, to verify that the "x" key is stuck.